# Can't populate angular form using ngModel and Model Object

Tags: angular, angular-forms, ngmodel

I have been practicing Angular framework for web development. Meanwhile I have used a model class user.ts:

```
 export class User {
    constructor(
        username: string,
        email: string,
        phone: number,
        choice: string,
        timePreference: string,
        promotional: boolean
    ){}
}
```

and the app.component.ts:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  topics=['angular','react','veu'];

  user = new User('Gull','gul@test.com',723893, '', 'morning', false);
}
```

Now I am using app.component.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Bootcamp enrollment form</h1>
  <form action="" #tempForm="ngForm">

    {{tempForm.value | json}}

    <!-- {{title}} -->
    <hr/>

    {{user | json}}

    <div class="form-group">
      <Label>Name:</Label>
      <input type="text" #name class="form-control" name="userName" [(ngModel)]="user.username">
    </div>
    {{name.class}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <Label>Email:</Label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="emailAddress">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <Label>Phone:</Label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.phone" name="phone">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="choice" id="" class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="user.choice" >
        <option value="">I am selected here</option>
        <option *ngFor="let top of topics">{{top}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="">Time preference</label>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="morning" name="timePreference" [(ngModel)]="user.timePreference">
        <label for="timePreference">Morning</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="evening" name="timePreference" [(ngModel)]="user.timePreference">
        <label for="timePreference">Evening</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="offers" name="promotional" [(ngModel)]="user.promotional">
        <label for="promotional">Send me promotional offers</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

In this code I am using tempForm as ngForm to show the entered value as template driven form, while I am `{{user | json}}` pipe for printing the value of model object. I have populated the model in app.component.ts, but here it didn't shows the controls populated with these values.

And the second problem is that `{{name.class}}` to see classes used by a control, did they work only with model driven forms?

I have also imported the FormsModule so that is not the error:

app.module.ts is:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,    
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now your `form` is binding the `user` instance in your component but it's properties are not visible to it.

> You need to define the `User` class properties as `public` for them to
>   be visible outside the class.

Example:

```js
export class User {
    constructor(
        public username: string,
        public email: string,
        public phone: number,
        public choice: string,
        public timePreference: string,
        public promotional: boolean
    ){}
}
```

Here is a working stackblitz example based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqcekz

Comment: Thanks so much. I love it. Such a blessing for developers especially for beginners.